# Updating via export-reimport: can I specify the value of a lookup field via a non-primary field in the target?

Tags: import, dynamics-crm-2011, updates

The question looks more complicated than the problem!

I want to use the import wizard to update a field that we have added to the Account record.  It is a lookup (foreign key) to a new entity, Constituency.  The Constituency entity includes a mandatory, unique field called Code.  I want to populate Account.Constituency by specifying Constituency.Code.

Steps:
- Create advanced find (AF) of Account.
- Add related Constituency to AF.
- Include Constituency Code in the AF output columns.
- Run the AF and export it to Excel (XML), selecting 'For re-import' option.
- Update the Constituency Code values in the spreadsheet.
- Import the modified spreadsheet.

All this seems to work and the import does not complain (all records import as updates; no failures), but the Account.Constituency field has not been updated - it remains null.  Does a lookup field have to be updated on import by either the GUID or the primary field of the related record, or am I missing something?

I cannot check the mapping via the front-end because the import wizard 'knows' how to map the XML and does not give an opportunity to alter it.  Inspecting the XML (I'm not an expert here) suggests that although the AF found the Constituency Codes, it did not add the set of possible values to the validation section of the export.

Any pointers welcome.

Answer (score 0):

How many records do you need to update?

because you can create one on-demand workflow to update that field, select the records and run the workflow.

Or you can also write a little C# application that will retrieve all the accounts and update the field, few lines of code.

Comment: Hi Guido, Thanks for your reply. There are about 15k records to update but the data is coming from outside the system.  I think that the import/update method will be OK if I use the primary (name) field, but I was interested to learn why it is restricted (if it is).  The C# option looks interesting though - could you point me towards an example, please?  Thanks again for your help.  Apologies for the poor formatting in this post, but I'm on a Windows 8 PC and it seems to ignore all the non-printable keys.  Simon.